# Symfony2 how not to escape characters used in entity field property

Tags: forms, symfony, escaping

I am using `Symfony 2.1.8` and I have form with an entity which has many-to-one relation on it.
I use entity field for this member and i call it in the `buildForm()` as:

> $builder->add('direction', 'entity', array(
>               'class' => 'CompanyBundle:Direction',
>               'property' => 'enTranslation.arrowedTitle',
>               'empty_value' => false,
>               'label' => 'Connection Direction',
>               'required' => false
>           ));

`enTranslation.arrowedTitle` is a function that returns a string which including `'&rArr;'` (character set for right arrow)

when i call `{{ form_widget(form.direction) }}` i see the string as it is,(not the arrow but the &rArr) For displaying purposes, arrows must be showed, but i see &rArr in the field.

For simple string rendering, `|raw`filter is used, but it does not work on widget. What should I do in order to display  ⇒ instead of '&rArr ;' in the form? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a form theme for at minimum the field type who's label includes that character.

Symfony/Twig escapes values by default for safety.

See this section of the documentation for more info:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#form-theming

Comment: Thx for help; Actually i was trying to override the choice_widget, but today i made it work. I created `fields.html.twig` file and overridden choice widget here as i wanted. However, isn't it possible to include to override in a template. such as `{% form_theme form 'StaffBundle:Form:field_errors.html.twig' %}
{% form_theme form 'CompanyBundle:Form:fields.html.twig' %}` When i include field.html.twig error display got broken. do you have an idea?

Comment: And i also resolved the issue, for multiple inclusion we should use strings in one line such as: `{% form_theme form  "StaffBundle:Form:field_errors.html.twig" "CompanyBundle:Form:fields.html.twig" %}`